# MSAccess VBA Enable/disable item on shortcut menu at runtime

Tags: vba, ms-access, shortcut

I use several custom Shotcut Menu Bars in my MSAccess solution.  If I use the built in shortcut menu bars they will automatically disable, grayed out, an item not available at the time of right clicking.  How can I replicate this during run-time on my custom shortcut menu bars? [Custom Shortcut Menu Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGZpF.png) In this example I would like to gray out the item "Send SMS" if the contact does not have mobile/cell number.  I currently do this by having two different shortcut menus that is set at runtime, depending on if the number is available.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! A shortcut is a key combo to do sth., you mean a context menu! See https://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons:Menus_Toolbars:Toolbars.

Comment: My question has to do with the shortcuts when right clicking on a particular field.  To set this shortcut in VBA for a field I use this command: Forms!AnyForm!AnyFiled.ShortcutMenuBar = "MyShortcut". Hope that makes sense.